# CGridView add another delete button with ajax post request

Tags: ajax, post, gridview, yii, cbuttoncolumn

Hello is it possible to add another delete button to Yii CGridView?
I would like it to make an ajax post request to one of mine controllers.

An use case would be:

Lets say I have a blog entry with comments. In administration I would like to have a gridview where I can delete this blog entry (this is already) possible. I would also like to have another delete button next to the original delete button which would only delete blog's comments (which I don't know how to add).

I looked over the HTML generated by Yii framework to see how the original delete button works. One possible solution would be to copy/paste that delete and refresh java script code and modify it a bit. But I don't like this. I have some concerns that if I do this, when I upgrade Yii framework there is no guarantee that my solution will still work.

Answer (score 4):

Use above tutorial and add class="delete" to the new button

```
'options'=>array('class'=>'delete')
```

Yii framework assigns ajax call to this class.

```
array('class'=>'CButtonColumn','template'=>'{remove}{view}{update}{delete}',
          'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'width:65px'),
          'buttons'=>array(
            'remove'=>array('url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("resolution/removeApp", array("id_application"=>$data->id_application,"id_resolution"=>'.$model->id_resolution.'))','label'=>'Remove application from resolution.','imageUrl'=>Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/remove.png','options'=>array('class'=>'delete')),
            ))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this [Using CButtonColumn to customize buttons in CGridView](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/106/using-cbuttoncolumn-to-customize-buttons-in-cgridview/)  to add a new button which will be calling the action in your controller to delete comments. Cheers.

Comment: I've already tried this by adding custom button to CButtonColumn's buttons property. Problem was that click element in button array doesn't get php evaluated (as url) so I can't pass row's id to my ajax post request.

Comment: I'm sorry then, because I guess I don't understand your question.